# Print nth index of enumerated list

Tags: python-3.x

I want to print the 5th index value of an enumerated list.  In the example code below, the 5th index value is 555.  I want to print only the 555 value. The code below prints all index values from 0-8.  I just want to print the value at index 5, which is 555.  What is the best way to do this?

```py
num_list = [000, 111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888]
for i, d in enumerate (num_list):
    print(i, d)
```

Comment: Do you just want `print(num_list[5])`, or `print(5, num_list[5])`?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying question.  I want to ```print(num_list[5])```, but I want to print the value 555 only once, not 9 times.

Comment: Just `print(num_list[5])`. Nothing else. No loop.

Comment: Being new to python, it appears I'm doing something wrong.  Replacing ```print(i, d)``` in the above code with ```print(num_list[5])``` results in 555 being printed 9 times.  How do I get it out of the loop so it only prints it once.  I'm using Sublime Text for testing.

Comment: If it's printing 9 times, you must be printing in a loop. Open a new file and write `num_list = [000, 111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888]`, then on the line under that write `print(num_list[5])`. Nothing else. Just those two lines.

Comment: That makes sense, however the condition is that it must be printed using the enumerated object, not a list.

Comment: Is this homework? They're telling you that you must use `enumerate`? Then just check the value of `i` in the loop, and only print if it's 5. In reality though, don't do that. Just use the code I showed you. You would never iterate a list just to print an element at a certain pre-known index.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue.  The goal was to print the value of the nth index (i.e. 5th index) of an enumerated object.  Additional the value should only be printed once.  I believe the problem with the code was the indented print statement.  Below is the solution.

```
num_list = [000, 111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888]
for i, d in enumerate (num_list):
    x = num_list[5]
print(x)
```

Comment: This works, but using `if i == 5: print(d); break;` in the loop makes much more sense. There's no point is reassigning the same thing over and over again and every iteration of the loop.